# Management system to database, draw statitistcs, cronjobs, network load etc

Tags: linux, python

I need to organize management system to my client on his server. I want in this system things like:

- show views from database and draw some charts based on it
- show tables from database
- maybe query editor to run custom queries (like phpmyadmin)
- manage cronjobs - similar like 'crontab -e' on linux
- some server statitstics - cpu overload, network traffic etc
- maybe some mailing system to generate raports by day and send summary to client

I want run this on VPS server with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

My client have several crawlers on server and have some statistics tables on database. The purpose is manage these information and display on something like management system/panel for someone who is not programmer.

I looking something in Google and I found:

- vespa control panel
- icinga2

Another idea is code this in Python/Django, put data via API and organize this system in 100% custom, but it's cost money and time. The best option for me is something like 'ready-to-use' tool/feature.

Anyone can comment on these tools? Will they fulfill their task? Or maybe somebody have another idea?

Comment: My experience with icinga2 is that it is not really more than a set of cron-runned testscripts and mail sender. Its documentation is a pile of crap, setting it up is harder than write your own testscripts. There is no working GUI, too.

Comment: Btw, I unsuggest you to use a one thing for all. It will be crap. Use a set of specialized tools and integrate them together. Use icinga for monitoring (possibly google for zabbix). Don't use control panel, all of them are crap, more clearly they are unsuitable for professional sysadming. You will have problems and you will have no idea where to even start to fix. And any pro, who you show your system, will vomit seeing it, and won't help. If there is no some special need, *learn that f...g command line*, so is it the easiest on the long-term!

Comment: Thanks for response. Yeah, I know that a learning command line and basics of programming is the best option, but I need this for my non-programmic client. If cronjobs and queries is too much that only charts drawing and stats tables is okay. What specialized tools for these problems you suggest?